# Get position of image in carousel and set text

Tags: java, android, xml, carousel

I am using an android library for displaying image in form of a carousel using https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview

How do I set a text depending on the image displayed in the carousel.

**I have a list of images in Array**

```
private int[] sampleImages = {R.drawable.image1, 
R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, 
R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5,   
R.drawable.image6};
```

**In my java code I have set a custom view Listener according to the doc**

```
ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_safety, null);

            title = customView.findViewById(R.id.safetyTextTitle);
            description = customView.findViewById(R.id.safetyTextDescription);
            safety_images = customView.findViewById(R.id.safetyImages);

            Glide.with(SafetyFragment.this).load(sampleImages[position]).into(safety_images);

            if(sampleImages[position]==1){
                description.setText("hahahhahahahahhaha");
            }

            return customView;
        }
    };

    carouselView.setPageCount(sampleImages.length);
    carouselView.setViewListener(viewListener);

   return root;
}
```

**As you can see, I tried to use this**

```
if(sampleImages[position]==0){
   description.setText("hahahhahahahahhaha");
 }
```

This is supposed to show the text "hahahhahahahahhaha" for the first image in the carousel, but its not displaying anything....How do I do this please??

**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tabContent"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner2">

    <com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
        android:id="@+id/carouselView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:fillColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        app:pageColor="#00000000"
        app:radius="6dp"
        app:slideInterval="5000"
        app:strokeColor="#FF777777"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"/>

  <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/safetyImages"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/safetyTextTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/safetyImages"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/safetyTextDescription"
        android:layout_below="@+id/safetyTextTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.